# Reorganize an array with es6 for items with same id

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have an array of products:

```
const products = [
 { title: 'test product', storefront: {id: 0, title: 'test storefront 1'} },
 { title: 'test product 2', storefront: {id: 0, title: 'test storefront 1'} },
 { title: 'test product 3', storefront: {id: 1, title: 'test storefront 2'} }
]
```

How would I return a new array that will contain an object for each storefront and all it's products?

For example:

```
  const storefronsts = [
    {
      storefront: {id: 0, title: 'test storefront 1'}, 
      products: [
        { title: 'test product', storefront: {id: 0, title: 'test storefront 1'} }, 
        { title: 'test product 2', storefront: {id: 0, title: 'test storefront 1'} }
      ]
    },
    {
      storefront: {id: 1, title: 'test storefront 2'}, 
      products: [
        { title: 'test product 3', storefront: {id: 1, title: 'test storefront 2'} }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: @MisterJojo oops. fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and then just check each storefront `id`

```
const rtn = products.reduce((p,c,i,a) => {
    let current = p.find(store => store.storefront.id == c.storefront.id);
    if (!current) { 
        current = { storefront: {id: c.storefront.id, title: c.storefront.title, products: []} }
        p.push(current);
    }

    current.storefront.products.push(c)
    return p;
}, [])
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/n1pfL8e6/

Answer (score 0):

The output (storefronts Array) can be compared with the requested Array (from the question) using JSON.stringify. The following code returns `true` for the comparison, whereas the accepted answer returns `false`.

**Original Input:**

```js
const products = [{
    title: 'test product',
    storefront: {
        id: 0,
        title: 'test storefront 1'
    }
},
{
    title: 'test product 2',
    storefront: {
        id: 0,
        title: 'test storefront 1'
    }
},
{
    title: 'test product 3',
    storefront: {
        id: 1,
        title: 'test storefront 2'
    }
}
];
```

**Transformation Process:**

```js
const pre = {}

products.forEach(product => {

  const storeFrontId = product.storefront.id;
  const { storefront } = product;
  if (pre[storeFrontId]) {
    return pre[storeFrontId].products.push(product);
  } 
  pre[storeFrontId] = { storefront, products: [ product ] }

});

const storefronts = [];

Object.keys(pre).map(key => storefronts.push(pre[key]));
// Alternative, cleaner version:
// Object.values(pre).map(value => storefronts.push(value) );

console.log(storefronts);
```

**Comparing with the original output:**

```js
const expected = [
    {
      storefront: {id: 0, title: 'test storefront 1'}, 
      products: [
        { title: 'test product', storefront: {id: 0, title: 'test storefront 1'} }, 
        { title: 'test product 2', storefront: {id: 0, title: 'test storefront 1'} }
      ]
    },
    {
      storefront: {id: 1, title: 'test storefront 2'}, 
      products: [
        { title: 'test product 3', storefront: {id: 1, title: 'test storefront 2'} }
      ]
    }
];

const expectedJSON = JSON.stringify( expected );
```

**Comparing our result with the expected structure:**

```js
console.log( JSON.stringify( storefronts ) === expectedJSON );
//=> true
```